# In MySQL, what are the practices to backup databases?

Tags: mysql, database, backup

I am using mysql

How often do you back up your database?

How do you normally backup your database?

Export all data into sql or cvs format and keep it in a folder??

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited for serverfault.com...

Comment: ... also, looks like you made a duplicate question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545/how-do-i-do-backups-in-mysql

Comment: it wasnt me.. sory  for didnt notice similar question.. my bad

Comment: This may be a bit late, and chances are.. you found your solution by now. But.. Dependant upon your backup needs, and your existing hosting solution, cPanel offers a good method creating auto backups.. or if this is something on a dedicated solution (hosted or otherwise) you can also try something like Zetta. But I'm not trying to insight a sound like I am spinning spamish comments so Ill leave off on that..

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a cronjob to run a script that does a mysqldump and stores the dump on a separate disk from the database itself (or a remote server) is a quite easy and efficient way to backup a database in my opinion. You could even have it dump every database with the `--all-databases` switch

If you have more than one MySQL server, you could also use [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)

Frequency of backups depends on how much data you are willing to lose in case of a failure.

Answer (score 0):

How Often - Depends on the activity and traffic you have on your Database.

I use phpMyAdmin and then click on the export tab and export the database as .sql

you can reach phpmyadmin by either localhost/phpmyadmin if you are running xampp/wamp/lamp etc or you can click on the 'phpmyadmin' link in your webhost's cPanel if you are hosting your webstie online.

Answer (score 0):

I backup databases daily, using 'mysqldump [options] db_name [tables]', and export all data into sql.
Of course, this depend on the size of your databases.

Answer (score 0):

I use `mysqldump`:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p database_name > ~/backups/database_name-$(date +%s).sql
```

Answer (score 0):

1.If you want the easiest way to back-up the database then you can opt for phpMyadmin.

2.If you prefer command line then follow this way.

You would simply modify the path and filename to reflect the specifics of your new backup file, like so:
C:\ mysql -uroot -p [DatabaseName] < C:/backups/[backUpDatabaseName.sql]

3.Mysql dump.
C:\ mysqldump [myDatabaseName] > [ExportDatabaseName]

Answer (score 0):

You can also look [hotbackup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782826/recommendable-hot-backup-system-for-mysql)